# Unable to for each over a view model child collection in an MVC 4 view

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-4

In my Index view I am returning a single Attorney and it's child's Associate collection from a ViewModel called AttorneyIndexViewModel. The Linq statemnts in my controller is retrieving the logged in Attorney along with a collection of child Associates.

My problem is when I foreach over the Associate collection in the Index view I'm forced to use Linq statements to access the ViewModel properties. When the view is displayed it only returns one of the three associates from the DB. I want to be able to access the associates collection like this "item.FirstName" but I'm forced to use "associate.AssociateList.FirstOrDefault().LastName", which is why I only list one of the three Associates.

This is my ViewModel

```
public class AttorneyIndexViewModel 
{
    public int AttorneyID { get; set; }
    public string AttorneyName { get; set; }
    public string AttorneyLawFirm { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Associate> AssociateList { get; set; }
}
```

Attorney Controller Index View

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // Find an Attorney from the current logged in users name which is his/her email address
        var user = unitOfWork.AttorneyRepository.Get(attorney => attorney.EmailAddress == GetLoggedInUser);

        var associate = unitOfWork.AssociateRepository.Get()
                        .Where(a=>a.AttorneyId == user.First().AttorneyID).ToList();

        var vModel = new List<AttorneyIndexViewModel>();
        foreach (var item in user)
        {
            vModel.Add(new AttorneyIndexViewModel
            {
                AttorneyID = item.AttorneyID,
                AttorneyName = String.Concat(item.FirstName, " ", item.LastName),
                AttorneyLawFirm = item.LawFirmName,
                // Fill the Associate list
                AssociateList = associate
            });
        }


        if (vModel.Any())
            return View(vModel.ToList());
```

And this is the portion of the view that displays an Attorneys Associates

```
@model IEnumerable<HopeRogWorks.ViewModel.AttorneyIndexViewModel>

// List of Associates
@foreach (var associate in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(a => associate.AssociateList.FirstOrDefault().FirstName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(a => associate.AssociateList.FirstOrDefault().LastName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(a => associate.AssociateList.FirstOrDefault().EmailAddress)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(a => associate.AssociateList.FirstOrDefault().TelephoneNumber)
        </td>
        <td>
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=associate.AssociateList.First().AssociateID }) |
    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=associate.AssociateList.First().AssociateID }) |
    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=associate.AssociateList.First().AssociateID })
```

Comment: Try `@foreach (var associate in Model.AssociateList)`

Comment: @Joe i think this will not work..instead you can try like this `@foreach (var associate in Model[0].AssociateList)`

Comment: @Nilesh, you're right, his Model is currently a list of `AttorneyIndexViewModel`.  Though his description ("In my Index view I am returning a single Attorney and it's child's Associate collection") it seems the intention is to have a model with a single element, so he probably wants something like Szilard Muzsi's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you're not getting what you're expecting is because you're actually iterating over the list of attorneys, and not the list of their associates. If you are sure that one e-mail address = one attorney (I suspect that is the case, as you were adding the same list of associates to all attorneys), then you should modify your user query to

```
var user = unitOfWork.AttorneyRepository.Get(attorney => attorney.EmailAddress == GetLoggedInUser).SingleOrDefault();
var associate = unitOfWork.AssociateRepository.Get()
                    .Where(a=>a.AttorneyId == user.AttorneyID).ToList();
var vModel = new AttorneyIndexViewModel
            {
                AttorneyID = user.AttorneyID,
                AttorneyName = String.Concat(user.FirstName, " ", user.LastName),
                AttorneyLawFirm = user.LawFirmName,
                // Fill the Associate list
                AssociateList = associate
            };

return View(vModel);
```

Then you no longer have to do a foreach over the users (but don't forget to also check that there is at least 1 attorney returned).
In the view you would then have something like this

```
@model HopeRogWorks.ViewModel.AttorneyIndexViewModel

// List of Associates
@foreach (var associate in Model.AssociateList)
{
 //code here
}
```

Comment: this will work if model has only one record..if there are multiple records then this will not work

Comment: yes, I know. But if he has more than one attorney for the same e-mail address, then he will need to also modify the list of associates, as in the current implementation he's associating the same list to all attorney ids.

Comment: There will be only one attorney returned with a list of his/hers associates in a collection. When I added the .SingleOrDefault() that Szilard recommended the foreach in my controller failed to compile foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'HopeRogWorks.Models.Attorney' because 'HopeRogWorks.Models.Attorney' does not contain a public definition for GetEnumirator

Comment: That's because you no longer need to do a foreach over the user, as you will only have 1 attorney in there. I updated the code in my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Your correct my mistake... I was wrong in looping over the Attorney that only returned a single user. Your example was spot on thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should display your data like this

```
@model IEnumerable<HopeRogWorks.ViewModel.AttorneyIndexViewModel>

@foreach (var item in Model) **Since you have use list means you have multiple data**
{
    foreach (var associate in item.AssociateList)
    { 

       @Html.DisplayFor(a => associate.FirstName)

    }
}
```